# jQuery each() only selects last value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 list.

the first list holds all data. The other one are placeholders. And I have a button to take the default values. Which clones the first list into the placeholders.

Now I'm using this code to `alert` all the found `data-id`'s. Which works fine.

But when I'm trying to paste those data-attributes onto the placeholders it always pastes the last value in each placeholder.

```
$(".default").click(function() {

    $("li.to-drag").each(function(index) {

        $("li.placeholder").addClass("dropped");

        var clone = $(this).clone();
        var day = $(this).attr("data-id");

            $("li.placeholder").each(function(){
                $("li.placeholder").attr("data-id", index);
            });

        clone.hide().appendTo("." + index).fadeIn(1500);

    });

    var dropped = $(".dropped").length;
    var original = $(".placeholder").length;

    if (dropped === original) {

        $("li.placeholder").removeClass(blank_placeholder);
        $("#dropzone").append('<li class="placeholder blank" data-id="" data-order=""></li>');

        init();
    }

});
```

How can I solve this?

**SOLUTION**:

I had to do a second `each()` loop outside the other one which iterated the `.to-drag` class.

```
$("li.placeholder").each(function(){
    var day = $(this).children().attr("data-id");
    $(this).attr("data-id", day);
});
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcmu496n/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `.each()` loop, you have to use `$(this)`, otherwise you will change everything everytime the loop repeats.

So just change the following part of your code:

```
$("li.placeholder").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("data-id", index);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. It still give me the last value.

Comment: what should happen if I press the button? I don't understand your problem right now

Comment: When pressed the button, the `.to-drag` element gets cloned into `.placeholder`. But the `.to-drag` holds a data-attribute, which should be copied into `.placeholder`

Comment: Found the solution thanks to the above code. I'll post it as an edit

Comment: Ok, now I understand your problem. Just change the second `.each()` to the following:
`$("li.placeholder."+index).attr("data-id", day);`
Because you don't need to loop through all placeholders, only to the one you want to change